# difference between gyro and accelerometer

Tags: objective-c, xcode

According to apple documentation , the accelerometer measures acceleration **along** the axis, and gyro measure the rotation rate **around** the axis .

In reality , things are very strange .

When using the accelerometer function:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
```

it seems that the gyro and accelerometer are working together .
When fast moving along the x axis, i get values bigger then 1 like 1.5-2 ,which is ok cause i get acceleration. but when rotating the iphone **AROUND** its x axis, the values also changing between 0-1, for example , if i hold it and the value is 0.3 ,and the i rotate it a little bit, i see 0.6, if i rotate more its 0.8.  but this is a behavior of  a gyro  , because when velocity is 0 (i stop the rotation) i should see  acceleration -0 and not 0.6 . it seems to show me the gyro angle position .

Whats happen here anyway ? the values should be 0, till i move it **fast ALONG  the axis** not around it .

I couldnt find any answer and it seems that many people dont really understand that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before All we must agree on terms:

In my opinion APPLE is wrong when it calls acceleration the values you get from sensor.
Acceleration in the second derivative of translation, so d(dx)/d(dt), so when  an iphone is steady, should be zero.
in my opinion these values are simply angles.
See apple samples, the use a "2nd order filter" to get acceleration.. "2nd" order filter means 2nd derivate, if I remember correctly what I studied.

Hope this can help.

Comment: i think you right, and one way to see it is that the iphone is measure the **F=mg*cos(a)** , so when placing the iphone on its side you get acceleration of earth which is 1g. (cos(a)=1, m=1 ) and when moving the iphone fast you get **F=mg*cos(a) + Fmove** , and then you get more than 1g . so physicaly speaking, there is some true in this, because when velocity is 0 ,there is acceleration of earth, not acceleration of **my movement velocity** .

Comment: Acceleration is the second derivative of position, not translation, and has no inherent geometric link. Do a quick Google for 'angular velocity' to see that the terms all translate straight across. It's also definitely not returning angles.

Answer (score 2):

The accelerometer reports the difference between the acceleration that the device is experiencing and that with it would be experiencing were it in freefall. So if the accelerometer is returning a zero vector then the only force acting on the phone is gravity (ie, you've dropped it). Normally it'll be some other value. If the phone is at rest on a table, it'll reveal the direction of gravity relative to the phone. The accelerometer is therefore most often used to figure out which way is down - so that the UI can rotate, and in games so that you can do things like use the device as a steering wheel.

The gyroscope can observe the rate at which the device is rotating. The CoreMotion library can automatically integrate that to get current angles.

Devices with a gyroscope also have a three-axis accelerometer (in addition to the traditional one) that measures acceleration individually along three axes.

Comment: Sure. But what ingconti speculates isn't accurate. The values returned by the accelerometer aren't angles in any sense. Your comment is quite right though. If you wanted to explain it physically, I guess you'd pretend there was a weight on a string in the phone and a sensor fixed tight to the shell that can report the direction of the string. If you sort of fudge the issue that the string can change length, of course.

Answer (score 0):

yes, what tommy says about my comment are true, they are not angles.
I used that measures in iOS 2.11 and I remembered them incorrectly.
Anyway the point we agree is that speaking of acceleration is wrong.
In Physics if I say a=1.0, it means a body is moving with a increasing velocity.
"g" is the acceleration of a body falling down, but when it is steady, its a = 0, even if gravity is present.